# AWS Simple Email Service Ruby SDK Version 1 works in rails c but not in ruby file. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to write a script in my Rails 4.2 application that will send an email using the Amazon SES API using the Ruby SDK version 1. For compatibility reasons with other gems, I need to use Version 1.

The problem that I am experiencing is that when I load the console with `rails c` I am able to execute these methods perfectly:

```
ses = AWS::SimpleEmailService.new
ses.identities.map(&:identity)
ses.send_email(.......)
```

so on and so forth. However, my script/amazon_ses.rb file seems to fail when I try to execute it and I'm not sure why that is.

Here is my initializer file:

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :amazon_ses,     
  AWS::SimpleEmailService,
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    region: 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    server: 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
```

This is my `script/amazon_ses.rb` file:

```
require 'aws-sdk-v1'

ses = AWS::SimpleEmailService.new
identity = ses.identities.map(&:identity)
ses.send_email(.......code.....)
```

`rescue in block in define_attribute_getter': unable to find the identity (AWS::Core::Resource::NotFound)`

I'm not sure what to make of this but I have the feeling that Core::Resource is not being loaded, inherited, included etc. Has anyone encounted this problem before?

Comment: how are you running it? Are you sourcing your environment / using bundler?

Comment: Doon, thanks for the reply. I am simply calling `ruby script/amazon_ses.rb`. It might just be late and I'm tired but could you please elaborate what you mean by sourcing my environment with bundler?

Comment: posted answer, mostly due to formatting.  but if you are running with just ruby, you need to source rails.  can also try running it with `./bin/rails runner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
```

to the top of your script.  This will pull in your rails environment.

or without adding the above try

```
 bin/rails runner script/amazon_ses.rb
```

Comment: So close! I think this is the right way to go, I got this error `gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/configuration.rb:31:in `application_root_path': Spring was unable to find your config/application.rb file.` I think all that's needed now is the `application.rb`.

Comment: hmm i've not tried it with spring, try removing the require and do it under rails runner.  normally the way I do something like this is make it task, and depend on the environment and then just run it with rake.

Comment: I appreciate the help Doon, I'm slowly getting there. I'm at least getting different errors `lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `amazon_ses' for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: I guess I really am tired. Your'e answer war right, I forgot that I was running the command a directory higher. So I needed to run `rails runner script/amazon_ses.rb`. Thanks for the life saver Doon. I really appreciate it!